# Embedding 2-dimensional manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I have this question: we have a 2-dimensional smooth manifold $M$. Thanks to Whitney's theorems we can embed $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Is there a result saying that we can embed $M$ also in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 1):

No. The Klein Bottle is a smooth $2$-manifold that cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Thanks. It is helpfull!